# How can I prevent processing.exe requiring network access?

Tags: windows-7, processing

Running processing.exe in Windows 7 here causes a firewall dialog requesting network access.

[image]

where uncheckmarking that box disables the Allow button.

How can I get this program to run without me allowing network access?

PS Processing.exe is the environment for the Processing language https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_(programming_language) .

Comment: what is processing.exe? What does it do?

Comment: I guess you want to disable Internet access to java runtime.

Comment: Vinayak, I would rather not, since that could adversely affect other programs.

Comment: "what is processing.exe?" Did you downvote the question because you don't know what processing.exe is? Processing.exe is the environment for the Processing language https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_(programming_language) .

Comment: @ChrisJJ - If a question is not clear, to a reader, they are often will downvote it.  If the Allow button is being disabled, are you running it from an account, which has the correct permissions?

Comment: "are you running it from an account, which has the correct permissions?" I've no idea what the correct permissions are - none are stated in the program's requirements - but I am running from a Admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Glasswire, has a built in firewall which can easily block programs from accessing the net. The program will still run but with no access to any web things. It shows the programs installed, click the "fire" icon to block them. If you need any help let me know, I use it for blocking a lot of programs on my machines.

https://www.glasswire.com/

This is one way to accomplish your task.

Comment: Thanks. I'll consider that if there's no solution without an extra program.